# How can I put a link on the right side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
a{
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    width: 160px;
    float: right;
}

p{
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<p>
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
<a href="#">Download</a>
</p>
```

All I'm trying to do is putting that button on the right side without setting `position: absolute;` to it. How can I do that?

Comment: `text` is not a valid HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in multiple ways, here's the ***Flexbox*** way:

```css
text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* vertical stacking */
  /* align-items: flex-end; affects all flex-items */
}

a {
  align-self: flex-end; /* affects only this flex-item */
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<text>
  some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
  <a href="#">Download</a>
</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: right` to it.

```css
a{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    width: 160px;  
}
```

```html
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
<a href="#">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I edited my question. `float` is something like `position: absolute`. It doesn't take any height. While I need to keep its height. Sorry I'm not good in English that's why I cannot explain what I mean correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `css`

```
display: block;
float: right;
```

```css
a{
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    width: 160px;
 
   display: block;
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<text>
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
<a href="#">Download</a>
</text>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I edited my question. `float` is something like `position: absolute`. It doesn't take any height. While I need to keep its height. Sorry I'm not good in English that's why I cannot explain what I mean correctly.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: add `overflow: auto` to the container.

```css
a{
display: block;
border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
border-radius: 100px;
text-align: center;
color: #222;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 15px;
transition: all .3s;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s;
width: 160px;

float: right;
}

div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<text>
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
<a href="#">Download</a>
</text>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I edited my question. `float` is something like `position: absolute`. It doesn't take any height. While I need to keep its height. Sorry I'm not good in English that's why I cannot explain what I mean correctly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Add `overflow: auto` to the container.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a{
    display: block;
    border: 3px solid #ffcb08;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    width: 160px;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<text>
some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here.
<a href="#">Download</a>
</text>
```

simply use: `float: right;`

Comment: Thank you, but I edited my question. `float` is something like `position: absolute`. It doesn't take any height. While I need to keep its height. Sorry I'm not good in English that's why I cannot explain what I mean correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with flexbox!

html :

```
<div class="container">
    <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor deleniti labore voluptatem eum, delectus aperiam, qui culpa voluptate adipisci ipsum. Doloribus labore facilis id inventore omnis reprehenderit perferendis unde aspernatur.
    </span>
    <a href="#">Download</a>
</div>
```

css :

```
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.container >p{
  flex:1;
}
.container >a{
  flex:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tfyrf630/